# What effect do modifiers have in declarations with qr operator?

Tags: regex, perl

Perldoc says:

```
 qr/STRING/msixpodual
```

So g is not allowed, which leads me to my question: What does putting in a modifier in a qr operator declaration do to the "stringified" (as perldoc reports it) version of that regex?

What I've been having at the back of my mind while doing this is that I have to use the g explicitly and whatever else modifier I'm adding subsequent to the declaration if it's been already mentioned with qr, it will be ignored.

```
my $var = qr /[A-Z]{1,2}/msix
```

Then in a conditional I would use

```
if ($string =~ /($var)/g )
  # work with match
```

Comment: Not sure what your question means. See for your self? `my $re = qr/foo/flags; print $re;`. You can use the modifiers which are allowed and make sense in `(?here:...)`. It doesn't make much sense for just a subexpression to have `/g`.

Comment: If I have a wall of a regex declaration for a single variable and plan on using it alone, it would make sense but I guess it's a marginal case. The question is the other part, what happens in the case of over-written modifiers going around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some flags affect the regex pattern. For example, `s` affects what `.` matches. These flags can be specified using `(?flags)` and `(?flags:...)`. These flags are accepted by all of the builtin operators that accept regex patterns (`qr//`, `m//` and `s///`).

Some flags affect the operator on which they can be used. For example, `e` causes the substitution operator to treat the replacement expression as code rather than a string literal. These flags can't be specified using `(?flags)` and `(?flags:...)`. These flags are only accepted by the operators for which these flags make sense.

---

Let's imagine `g` did apply to `qr//`.

```
my $re1 = qr/abc/;    # Match once
my $re2 = qr/def/g;   # Match globally

... $x =~ /$re1$re2/ ...
```

What would that do? It simply makes no sense.

`g` has nothing to do with regex patterns. You can't apply `g` to just part of a pattern. `g` is necessarily an operator flag.

---

Stringification should produce an accurate representation of the pattern, but the flags are part of the pattern's definition. As such, the stringification should include the flags. This is done by embedding the pattern in `(?flags:...)`.

```
$ perl -E'say qr/abc/'
(?^u:abc)                     # Default flags

$ perl -E'say qr/abc/i'
(?^ui:abc)                    # Default flags plus "i"

$ perl -E'
   $re1 = qr/a/;
   $re2 = qr/b/i;
   say $_, ": ", /$re1$re2/ ? 1 : 0 for qw( ab aB Aa AB );
'
ab: 1
aB: 1
Aa: 0
AB: 0
```